# Problem about ActiveRecord Templates for SQLite

Tags: sqlite, activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

I try to using the SQLite in SubSonic.Examples.ActiveRecord project so:

1. Add a reference for System.Data.SQLite
2. Copy the SQLite.ttinclude and Settings.ttinclude from \T4 Templates\TemplateProviders\ to the Models_Generated\
3. Change the <#@ include file="SQLite.ttinclude" #> in the SQLite.ttinclude and Settings.ttinclude
4. Change the settings: Namespace, ConnectionStringName, DatabaseName to "Blog" in the Settings.ttinclude file.

I meet two errors when regenerate the code:
first one is because of missing a "break" at SQLite.ttinclude line #80

```
case "long":
case "integer":
    sysType= "long";
    break;  // missing a break
case "guid":
```

After add a "break" the code file "Context.cs" can generate successfully, but the ActiveRecord.cs can not generate, there is a Warning:

***Multiple template directives were found in the template. All but the first one will be ignored. Multiple parameters to the template directive should be specified within one template directive. D:\LP\Study\SubSonic 3 Final\Examples\SubSonic.Examples.ActiveRecord\Models_Generated\Settings.ttinclude   1   4***

Comment: A warning shouldn't stop the t4 files from generating. Are you using the express version of VS or is there another error. Also what happens if you right click and 'Run custom tool' on the ActiveRecord.tt file?

Answer (score 1):

I download the latest version from SubSonic's [github](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master) and everything is OK!

The new version a new T4 file: **Structs.tt**